# Defining a click event programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I am creating a dynamic anchor tag like this

```
 var anch = $('<a />', {
                        'href': '#' + ctrlid,
                        'text': text
                    })
```

How do I add a click event while creating this tag that automatically calls a function say funcOne(ctrlid) and passes the ctrlid?

I tried this but no luck

```
 var anch = $('<a />', {
                        'href': '#' + ctrlid,
                        'text': text,
                        'onclick': funcOne(ctrlid)
                    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var anch = $('<a />', {
    'href': '#' + text,
    'text': text,
     on: {
         click: function () {
            // do something
         },
         someOtherEvent: function () {
            // do something
         }
     }
});
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rd98j/1/)

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 6):

```
var anch = $('<a />', {
    'href': '#' + ctrlid,
    'text': text
}).click(function () {
    // click handler code
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KbKyW/1/)**